# How to generate the expected output by using split method used in my code?

Tags: ruby

Question:

> Create a method for Array that returns a hash having 'key' as length of the element and value as an array of all the elements of that length. Make use of `Array#each`.
>
> Returned Hash should be sorted by key.

I have tried to do it through Hash sorting over length. I have almost resolved it using another method but I want to use split and hash to achieve expected output.

Can anyone suggest any amendments in my code below?

Input argument:

```
array-hash.rb "['abc','def',1234,234,'abcd','x','mnop',5,'zZzZ']"
```

Expected output:

```
{1=>["x", "5"], 3=>["abc", "def", "234"], 4=>["1234", "abcd", "mnop", "zZzZ"]}
```

```
class String
  def key_length(v2)
    hash = {}
    v2.each do |item|
      item_length = item.to_s.length
      hash[item_length] ||= []
      hash[item_length].push(item)
    end
    Hash[hash.sort]
  end
end

reader = ''
if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
else
  v1 = ARGV[0]
  v2 = v1.tr("'[]''",'').split
  p reader.key_length(v2)
end
```

Actual output:

```
{35=>["abc,def,1234,234,abcd,x,mnop,5,zZzZ"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the array (converted from string, note integers as string between ""):

```
ary = str[1..-2].delete('\'').split(',')
ary #=> ["abc", "def", "1234", "234", "abcd", "x", "mnop", "5", "zZzZ"]
```

The most "idiomatic" way should be using group_by:

```
ary.group_by(&:size)
```

If you want to use each, then you could use [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), where the object is an [Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) with an empty array as default:

```
ary.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = []}) { |e, h| h[e.size] << e }
```

Which is the same as

```
res = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = []}
ary.each { |e| res[e.size] << e }
```

Comment: Thanks.. that was a great add to my knowledge.

Comment: @AbhinavKannojia Accept & upvote answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to monkeypatch* array here, is this a school exercise or something?

I think your bug is you need to pass in the comma delimiter arg to split.

I would solve the underlying problem as a reduce/inject/fold thing, myself.

```
s = "['abc','def',1234,234,'abcd','x','mnop',5,'zZzZ']"
splits = s.tr("'[]''",'').split(',') # need to pass in the comma for the split
Hash[splits.inject({}) { |memo,s| memo[s.length] ||= []; memo[s.length] << s; memo }.sort] # doesn't use Array.each but?
```

> {1=>["x", "5"], 3=>["def", "234"], 4=>["1234", "abcd", "mnop"],
>   5=>["['abc"], 6=>["zZzZ']"]}

Comment: Thanks.. I can't believe, I did this silly mistake.